# Connecting Nokia Lumia 620 to Desktop with Windows XP

Tags: sync, lumia, pc

I have windows XP home edition in my desktop. when I connect my New Nokia Lumia 620, it does not recognise it. Windows explorer does not show Nokia connected. It used to recognise Nokia N73 thru Nokia PC Suite.

Please help anyone.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like in My Computer when you connect your Windows Phone?

Answer (score 4):

Windows Phone 8 devices use MTP for file transfers. MTP is supported under Windows XP after installing Windows Media Player 10 or higher.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol#Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Lumia 620 is not supported by either of the Nokia Suites. This [link](http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Nokia-Lumia/New-function-in-Nokia-Suite-to-transfer-contacts-to-a-Lumia/td-p/1559920) may help

You may still have an issue on Win-XP ... time to update! Frankly my experience installing Win-7 on XP pc's has been very good, you should benefit tremendously both performance & stability wise by upgrading to Win-7

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [desktop sync program](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/get-the-sync-apps)? This is the program developed by Microsoft for all Windows Phone 8 devices to interact and transfer items to and from the phone. It will also back up the items if you choose it as well.

If that doesn't work for you Microsoft has a [sync wizard](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/sync-wizard) that will tell you how you can access the features of your phone using the current configuration of your computer.

Comment: Desktop sync program is for Win7/8, not even for Vista, not to mention XP.

Comment: If you continue to read my answer, you can use the sync wizard link I provided and Microsoft will give you instructions how to sync with Vista and XP. Windows Media Player and Windows Explorer can be used with the older systems per the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution for all Nokia phones with this issue whether its symbian or windows, install [NOKIA PC SUITE](http://nds1.nokia.com/files/support/global/phones/software/Nokia_PC_Suite_ALL.exe)

I know it sounds odd, the PC Suite has nothing to do with Windows Phones, but it still worked for me.

I think it may install drivers, especially the legacy driver. Install it, and view your phone in my computer using file explorer.

This is for xp

Answer (score -1):

"Windows Phone not detected by XP"- Solved After lots of reaserch finally i got solution-

1. If XP detects as camera then uninstall Nokia RM846 diver & Camera driver. For this Go to device manager  right click on `my computer->manage->device manager->Imaging->lumia camera->Rt click -> unistall`   also unistall Nokia RM 846 by right click. Now your phone will be get detected as MTP device. This only syncronizes phones Mp3 with media player. To access sd card by using xp do following 2nd step
2. Go to device manager  Rt click on `my computer->manage->device manager->portable device->mtp device->Rt click->scan for hardware changes` . After this pc will detect your windows phone with name eg. Lumia620/720 etc.  Now you can access files & folders

Answer (score -4):

You need to download and install [Zune Software](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-za/how-to/wp7/zune-software)
Unfortunately, it is supported only on XP SP3 and above, so if you can, upgrade home edition first to service pack 3 and you will have all the features

Comment: Zune is for WP7, the 620 is WP8.